# How to add new route dynamically in Nuxt2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs2

I have routes, which depend on domain of the site.

Previously I used `extendRoutes`. Now, I can't use it, because I use the one copy for different domains.

I have tried use `router.addRoute` in nuxtServerInit and in the middleware, but didn't work.

```
    const routes = app.router.getRoutes();
    const { components } = routes.find(route => route.path === '/about')

    app.router.addRoute({
      path: '/about-test',
      name: 'about111',
      component: components['default']
    });
```